# How to set a variable based on compare old and new value of object

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, compare, asp.net-web-api2

I am looking for a c# equivalent of a javascript watch function. Ive see n some different examples but they seem to be more than it is needed for my question. I have a variable in a web api controller set at "0". If a value properties in a object change I to change the variable to "1"

object to watch

```
public class parameters
{
    public string foo { get; set; }
    public string bar { get; set; }
    public string widget { get; set; }
}
```

Api Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    public string Post([FromBody]parameters parameters)
    {
      // initial value
      string bChanged = "0";

       //if any property value in parameters changes
      string bChanged = "1";
    }
```

Comment: How do you persist the previous value?  Is it store in a database or something?

Comment: im in angular thinking mode so I would just store in a new object variable? what do I need to do in this situation?

Comment: Can you raise an event in setters?

Comment: do i know how to do it? no. can i make any changes needed? yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write extension methods to check whether an object values  changed or not.

```
public static class Extensionparameters
 {
    private static parameters _initialParameters;

    public static void RegisterObject(this parameters parameters)
    {
        _initialParameters = parameters;
    }

    public static String CheckChanges(this parameters value)
    {
        if (value.bar != _initialParameters.bar || value.foo != _initialParameters.foo ||
            value.widget != _initialParameters.widget)
        {
            return "1";
        }
        return "0";
    }
}
```

Then in your code you can do it this way

```
[HttpPost]
public string Post([FromBody]parameters parameters)
{


       var initial = new parameters {bar = "a", foo = "a", widget = "a"};
       initial.RegisterObject();
       var changed = new parameters {bar = "v", foo = "a", widget = "a"};
       string bChanged=  changd.CheckChanges();

}
```

Comment: Take precautions with threading issues. The 'static' property will exist only once and could be overwritten by simultaneous calls.

Comment: @lcryder you're right,but those precautions is not on me ,it's on him.furthermore he didn't mentioned anything about multithreading